Mobile navbar does not automatically close afer clicking a link inside the navbar
I created a responsive mobile navbar with a toggle button. One can open and close the toggle button by clicking on it. However when the links inside the mobile navbar are clicked, the page scrolls down to the respective section but the mobile navbar remains open.
I tried to create a cons links and select all the links with getElementById and to remove the status active but after the link being clicked but the code does not work.


const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn')
const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn i')
const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')

toggleBtn.onclick = function() {
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle('open')
  const isOpen = dropDownMenu.classList.contains('open')
  toggleBtnIcon.classList = isOpen ? 'fa-solid fa-xmark' : 'fa-solid fa-bars'
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css"/>

<button class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" id="links">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" id="links">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" id="links">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" id="links">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




I made you a snippet. Please click [edit] then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and correct the toggle button, add CSS and some of the divs you link to plus the relevant framework/fontawesome from CDN

Change from id to class as id names cannot be same so
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="links">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" class="links">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

Add this into your Js your code will work
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.links')
      links.forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', () => {
      dropDownMenu.classList.remove('open')
      toggleBtnIcon.classList = 'fa-solid fa-bars'
}); });

Working Demo


const toggleBtn = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn")
const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector(".toggle-btn i")
const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu")

toggleBtn.onclick = function() {
  dropDownMenu.classList.toggle("open")
  const isOpen = dropDownMenu.classList.contains("open")
  toggleBtnIcon.classList = isOpen ? "fa-solid fa-xmark" : "fa-solid fa-bars"
}

// ADDED
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".links")
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dropDownMenu.classList.remove("open")
    toggleBtnIcon.classList = "fa-solid fa-bars"
  })
})
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.open {
  display: initial;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" />

<button class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>

<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="links">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="links">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




@Yogi, could you please tell me what I might be missing here and what additional changes are needed? I generated the demo code and ran it, and it works fine in that context. Could you help me identify where I might be going wrong

@yogi Ok got you point thanks ,I have updated the code feel free to check and update me if i am wrong
